# C# why is the Guid Property always coming back empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, guid

I am using mvc4 and have a Guid Property in a class and it looks like this

```
public Guid myGuid { get;set;}
```

I have a form that gives that Guid field a value

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.myguid, new { @Value = Guid.NewGuid() })
```

When I submit the form and do a breakpoint I can see that the Guid has a value however when it is saved in the database it returns empty such as 0000-0000-000 every single time what can be missing here?

The form values get saved like this

```
 public myModel CreateForm(myModel model)
 {
     var nModel = MapToDbModel(model, new myModel());       
     _context.myModel.Add(nModel);

     _context.SaveChanges();

     return model;
}
```

Comment: Is that property mapped to the DB? And do you see that property set correctly if you put a breakpoint in CreateForm -> nModel?

Comment: Yes it is mapped to the DB and I just did that and it is mapped correctly